# Windows Media Services server streaming to JWPlayer over RTSP, error "no playable sources found"

Tags: jwplayer, rtsp, windows-media-services, windows-media-server

So I have a Windows Media Services server that acts as our 'primary' distribution method for streaming live video content. I recently took note that there are RTSP and HTTP options in WMS, and am exploring utilizing that.

Right now, I am using JWPlayer, and coming back with 'no playable sources found'.

I've ensured that I am using the IP that WMS is bound to, and the current/native RTSP and HTTP ports ( 554 and 80 ), And that the plugin is enabled at the server level.

My question at this point May be as simple as 'What is the expected URL scheme/syntax for a Live stream from WMS over RTSP or HTTP'; but may be a bigger question - like 'is my JWPlayer set properly, or will it even support RTSP or HTTP from WMS'.

I am aware that JWPlayer doesn't support MMS, but RTSP and HTTP are not MMS.

Any thoughts would be marvelous.

```
jwplayer.key = 'KEY';
jwplayer('JWPlayer').setup({
    image: '',
    height: '480px',
    width: '640px',
    skin: 'stormtrooper',
    autostart: '',
    provider: 'rtsp',
    playlist: 
    [{
        sources: 
        [
            { file: 'rtsp://IP:554/LIVEPUBLISHINGPOINT' },
            { file: 'http://IP:80/LIVEPUBLISHINGPOINT' }
        ]
    }]
});
```

For the record, I'm using the cloud hosted JWPlayer.

Similarly, I can confirm that data is coming across that publishing point in MMS protocol, with roughly the same variables.

RTSP and HTTP over WMS are referenced [here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc770781(v=ws.10).aspx).

Comment: RTSP or MSS is not supported by the JW Player - http://support.jwplayer.com/customer/portal/articles/1403635-media-format-support

Comment: I was under the impression that JWPlayer supports RTSP... There's specific references in their documentation for RTSP from Wowza. I know that it doesn't support MMS, otherwise I would have accomplished that long ago - but it Does support HTTP and RTSP streaming; the question is more-likely 'Does anyone know what URL WMS expects, in order to deliver RTSP or HTTP streams'.

Comment: Edited your title as "does anyone have experience with...?" means opinion based and would be closed fast.

Comment: Fair enough. Thanks @AndreDaniel.

Comment: @EthanJWPlayer - I might go on to ask, what is the difference in WMS serving HTTP and/or RTSP, versus Wowza doing the same ( even most-specifically, HTTP )?

Comment: RTSP is not a protocol JW Player has ever supported. Where did you read that it was? It definitely isn't. If you are using Wowza, you should use their RTMP streams, or HTTP (HLS / M3U8), which are both supported by JW Player. Wowza supports RTSP still for very legacy purposes (old devices such as very old Androids and Blackberry for example, possibly Windows Phones).